# Mysterious working of a Javascript - forth value returns no exception when array defined for three

Tags: javascript

The below code works fine in javascript

```
var items = [1,2,5]
for (var i = 0, item; item = items[i]; i++) {
  console.log(item = items[i]);
}

OUTPUT : 1 2 5
```

1. I am not sure how this program works successfully
2. The forth item is undefined and what will happen in the last iteration.
3. Can we able to create a similar function in Java ?
4. items[3] at the end how it will be handled in the above function?

Comment: This is why people should not write code like this :).

Comment: It is a workable code kapa but would like to know in detail how it works...

Comment: As an aside, "it is a workable code" doesn't mean that this is a good way of writing loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two key things to start with:

First, in JavaScript, whenever you try to retrieve the value of an object property that doesn't exist (including an array entry), the result of the retrieval is the value `undefined`.

Second, when you use a value like a flag, as in an `if` statement or the "test" part of a `for` (or any other loop), etc., JavaScript with "coerce" whatever value you used to be boolean. [This is different from (say) Java, which requires that you only use `boolean` variables as that sort of flag.] Because JavaScript does this and it comes up a lot, we use the terms "truthy" (coerces to `true`) and "falsey" (coerces to `false`) to categorize values. The "falsey" values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course `false`; all other values are truthy.

Okay, armed with that information, let's look at your loop:

> The forth item is undefined and what will happen in the last iteration.

There are only three iterations. A `for` statement is made up of three expressions separated with `;`, and a loop body. The expressions are the *initialization*, the *test*, and the *increment*:

```
//          /--------------------------------initialization
//          |               /--------------- test
//          |               |           /--- increment
//   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  vvv
for (var i = 0, item; item = items[i]; i++) {
```

The loop is evaluated like this:

1. Do the initialization
2. Do the test
3. If the test was false, terminate
4. Do the body
5. Do the increment
6. Go back to step 2

The "test" part of your `for` loop is `item = items[i]`, which is an assignment. The value of an assignment expression is the value being assigned. So when `i` is `3`, that assignment is `item = items[3]` which is effectively `item = undefined`. That assignment has the value `undefined`, which is a falsey value, so the body of the loop isn't run a fourth time.

> Can we able to create a similar function in Java ?

Yes, it looks almost identical other than that with Java, you use a type with the variables, and you can't use (just) the `item = items[i]` thing for the "test" part of the `for` (for the same reason you get an exception below).

> `items[3]` at the end how it will be handled in the above function?

You don't have any function in your question. After the loop, in *JavaScript*, accessing `items[3]` would give you `undefined` (see above). In Java, it result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

---

Side note: The `=` in this line is an *assignment*, not a comparison:

```
console.log(item = items[i]);
```

If you meant to compare them, do this:

```
console.log(item == items[i]);
```

...which will give you the output

```
true
true
true
```

Comment: The problem is the code works fine...we have only i++. so at the end will the code check for items[3]  or not???? it is not throwing exception as you said..please clarify

Comment: where this the condition in the above for loop?  ex: for(int i=0;i<5;i++); in this case we are saying i<5...similarly what is the condition in the above for loop and it is working...

Comment: @user2323036: I said the exception would happen **in Java**. Java and JavaScript are only similar syntactically. There is no exception **in JavaScript** because of the way JavaScript handles it when you try to retrieve an object property (in this case, an array entry) that doesn't exist.

Comment: so, it means Javascript won't thrown an exception you retrieve an object which doesn't have value...will it always returns null..if yes how the above loop did not run for 4 times..

Comment: @user2323036 your loop condition is "item = items[i]". The first time this condition is checked, it evaluates to 1 which is treated as true, so the first iteration goes ahead. Second time we check, it evaluates to 2, treated as true, second iteration goes ahead. Third time, it evaluates to 5, treated as true, third iteration goes ahead. Fourth time we check, it evaluates to "undefined", which is treated as false, so we DO NOT get a fourth iteration at all. Your loop only runs three times.

Comment: @user2323036: Not `null`, `undefined`. I've added a bit to the answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what happens in your loop:

```
1. i = 0; item = 1; i = 1;
2. item = 2; i = 2;
3. item = 5; i = 3;
4. item = undefined; --> breaks the loop
```

Notice, that if you'd have `items = [0,1,2]`, your loop would never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine as you have `assignment` in the *for loop condition check*

During the first iteration item is `undefined` but it executes the loop without termination as you assign the first value of array to item and it is no more `undefined`

Try it with comparision operator as `item == items[i]`, you will find your loop no more executes even once.

When it comes outside of array i.e. `items[3]` which returns `undefined` and thus `temp` goes `undefined` and terminates the loop as in javascript `undefined`, `null`, `0`  and `false` all are same.

This function wont work in `Java` as it would complain that it requires condition not the assignment in for loop.